# Google Sheets - Run script with Sheet Protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, rows

I'm having an issue with my google sheet. Everything works fine on the owner view, but when I tried to share it to an editor, some function didn't go as I planned. As an owner, I use the protected sheets and ranges function. So, I used the protect sheet, then the except certain cells function so that editors can edit within that range. I put a two buttons to hide (for the rows that is empty) and show rows. The script is working fine since it worked on the owner view, but when I opened it to the editor view, there's an error that says "Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.". The range within the except certain cells is in the F column only. What should I do with this?

[image]

I'm using this code to hide the emplty rows.

```js
var startRow = 9;
var colToCheck = 2; // Column B

function shouldHideRow(ss, rowIndex, rowValue) {
  if (rowValue != '') return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex + 1, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  return true;
}

function HideRows() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var elements = ss.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
    if (shouldHideRow(ss, i, elements[i][0])) {
      ss.hideRows(startRow + i);
    }
  }
  // Hide the rest of the rows
  var totalNumRows = ss.getMaxRows();
  if (totalNumRows > numRows)
    ss.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
}
```

Here's the sample spreadsheet: [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCghGbJzFzE5WwK6M5QG-fRRY4aLWkhuJZr7gOBwuUs/edit?usp=sharing)

I hope that someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your situation, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095/7108653 In this thread, in order to run the script as the owner of Spreadsheet, Web Apps is used. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, but it doesn't work the way that I want it to be. I just want the user to hide the empty rows, but the user can't because of the cells are protected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your replying, you tested the method of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095/7108653 . But it's `it doesn't work the way that I want it to be.`. Is my understanding correct? In your situation, I thought that to run the script as the user might be the reason of your issue. So in order to run the script as the owner of Spreadsheet, I proposed to run the script using Web Apps like the thread. But if I misunderstood your situation, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike everything works fine with the owner side. But when I clicked the button on the user side, it shows the error. So my problem is on the user side. Is it possible that when I click the button to hide the empty rows, the protection will be removed then it will be protected again after running the whole hide row script?

Comment: @Tanaike and it's fine. I really appreciate that you are helping me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that to use Web Apps might be the solution of your issue. Because when the user is run your current script, the script is run as the user. I thought that by this, such error occurs. So I would like to propose to use the Web Apps for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I'm still getting the same error`, I cannot understand about your current situation. So can you provide the script and the detail flow for replicating your current issue? If you can do, please add them to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, I thought that this thread might be also useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666605/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike I already put the sample spreadsheet of what I'm trying to make.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. In order to run the script as the owner of Spreadsheet, I proposed to run the script using Web Apps like https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095/7108653 . But when I saw your current script in your shared Spreadsheet, I couldn't find the script using my proposals. So I cannot understand about the reason of `I'm still getting the same error`. I apologize for this. If your script was old script before my proposals are not reflected, can you update it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm so sorry. I thought you wanted to see it on how I did it first. I already edited the file. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. When I saw your updated script, I noticed that your script is same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64086330). I proposed the threads as the methodology. So the same script cannot be directly used for your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In your case, your script is required to be run by owner even when user is run script. For this, Web Apps is used. Yesterday, I answered to similar situation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666605 I think that this might be useful. If you cannot understand, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike not your fault. I'm still new with this script coding that's why I guess it felt so hard. I'm sorry. Will this process be able to work even if the one who will use it is an editor/user?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your situation. So I proposed the modified script reflected the workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that the proposed script worked. But if that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I can't make it work so maybe the problem is me? I tried the one you sent, the one that duplicates. It works fine with the user since it duplicates and the protection is removed, meaning the user became the owner, right? But I don't want it to be duplicated. I just want the user to hide rows when they clicked the hide rows button.

Comment: @Tanaike the solution that you have given below works. Thank you so much Tanaike! I really appreciate you for helping me with this. :)

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that your question could be resolved by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike you're welcome and don't be so sorry in things. You really helped us with things like this. Alright! Till my next issue with this script coding things. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your Spreadsheet, the protected sheet and ranges are used.
- You want to run your script when the users who are not the owner run the script.

  - In your current issue, when the user runs the script, an error occurs by the protected range.

### Modification points:

I thought that the method for resolving your issue is always to run the script as the owner. For this, in this case, I would like to propose to use Web Apps. In this case, I thought that this might be the same situation of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666605). But from your script, I thought that to reflect the thread to your script as the methodology might be a bit difficult. So I would like to propose the modified script as an answer.

In this answer, in order to run the script as the owner of Spreadsheet, the Web Apps is used.

### Usage:

At first, please delete the GAS project included `doGet` from your shared Spreadsheet.

#### 1. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it.

```
function doGet(e) {
  this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}

function HideRows() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=script_HideRows&sheetName=" + activeSheet.getSheetName(), {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

// DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for the access token.
}

function showRows() {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=script_showRows", {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
}

var startRow = 6;
var colToCheck = 2; // Column L

// This script is the same with your "HideRows".
function script_HideRows(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var elements = ss.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
 
  for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
    if (shouldHideRow(ss, i, elements[i][0])) {
      ss.hideRows(startRow + i);
    }
  }
  // Hide the rest of the rows
  var totalNumRows = ss.getMaxRows();
  if (totalNumRows > numRows)
    ss.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
};

// This script is the same with your "showRows".
function script_showRows() {
  // set up spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // get sheet
    var sh = sheets[i];

    // unhide columns
    var rCols = sh.getRange("1:1");
    sh.unhideColumn(rCols);

    // unhide rows
    var rRows = sh.getRange("A:A");
    sh.unhideRow(rRows);
  }
};

function shouldHideRow(ss, rowIndex, rowValue) {
  if (rowValue != '') return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  if (ss.getRange(startRow + rowIndex + 1, colToCheck, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge()) return false;
  return true;
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, the access token is required to request to Web Apps.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".

#### 3. Test this workaround.

Please click the buttons assigned with `HIDE ROWS` and `SHOW ROWS`. By this, the script is run by the owner. By this, even when the user is clicked the button, the result of script is the same with that run by the owner.

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- Related questions

  - [How to enable not authorized users to protect the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095)
  - [Changing Owner of the Sheet irrespective of the duplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666605)

Comment: Hello! Can you explain what this code `this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null);` do?

Comment: At `this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null);`, in this case, the function of the value of `e.parameter.run` is run with the argument of the value of `e.parameter.sheetName || null`. For example, it is the same with `script_HideRows(sheetName)` and `script_showRows()`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this again. It doesn't work with the users.