# Google Sheets: Hide rows in multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

I'm trying to hide rows across a multiple sheets. So I have a 6 sheets, but there are 4 similar sheets, the other one is more likely a summary of that 4 sheets and the other one is the sheet with a button. Here's a sample for your reference: [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sxGqNcmaTG8045AI6w1noIIYDcYtp5dfMVmaoYc-SQA/edit?usp=sharing)

It is working if I will put a HIDE ROWS button on sheets one by one, but it will take a lot of time for me to do it since I need to put it on different spreadsheets. My idea is to put a button per spreadsheet or upon opening it, the rows that are empty will be hidden. The SHOW ROWS button is perfectly working with it.

Here's the script that I'm using: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689629/6729785)

PROBLEM:

- Hide rows across multiple sheets with similar templates
- Summary sheets rows should be hidden together with 4 sheets (not same rows)

I hope that someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: About the sheets of `"MS_Q1", "MS_Q2", "MS_Q3", "MS_Q4"`, the hide rows are the same. Is my understanding correct? And. can I ask you about the detail of `not same rows` of `Summary sheets rows should be hidden together with 4 sheets (not same rows)`?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, it is correct. The summary sheet starts in different rows, but I want it also to be hidden when I click the hide row button.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike it kinda worked, but there's a problem. Row 9 & 10 are not hidden on the Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4. I edited the sample sheet for you to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Using your script, you want to run the script for several sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, when a button is clicked.

  - In your sample Spreadsheet, you want to run the script for the sheets of `"MS_Q1", "MS_Q2", "MS_Q3", "MS_Q4", "SUMMARY"`.
  - For "SUMMARY" sheet, the start row is different from others. It's `7`.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, for [the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689629), I would like to propose to modify the function `script_HideRows`.
- At first, the sheet names you want to run the script are set. And, using the sheet names, the script is run.

When above points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `script_HideRows` of [the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689629) as follows.

```
function script_HideRows() {
  var sheetNames = ["MS_Q1", "MS_Q2", "MS_Q3", "MS_Q4", "SUMMARY"];  // Please set the sheet names here. In this case, 4 sheets are used.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      if (sheetName == "SUMMARY") {  // When the sheet is "SUMMARY", the start row is changed.
        startRow = 7;
      }
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- If the script is not changed even when you copied and pasted above script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: it kinda worked, but there's a problem. Row 9 & 10 are not hidden on the Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4. I edited the sample sheet for you to see it.

Comment: @user6729785 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your updated Spreadsheet, I noticed that the value of `startRow` was changed. Why did you change it? Before it is not changed, it was `var startRow = 6`. But now, it's `var startRow = 11`. I think that the reason of your new issue is due to this. How about this? When I tested the modified script with `var startRow = 6`, your issue in your replying cannot be found. Can you confirm this again?

Comment: sorry about that. I forgot that I changed it since I tried it on the spreadsheet that I'm working on. I have already edited it and it is working on the template that I have given. Thank you again for helping me. :)

Comment: I'm having a problem with the code that you gave. As you can see in the sheets, I tried to put a number in the column A, the spreadsheet that I'm working on has it. The last one didn't hide after clicking the button. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @cjvdg About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. About this, I have to apologize. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?