# Google Sheets: Hide rows if a certain cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rows

I'm working now on hiding a row if a certain cell is empty. The code for hiding a rows works, but I encountered a problem with it. Here's a sample spreadsheet that I'm trying to do: [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sxGqNcmaTG8045AI6w1noIIYDcYtp5dfMVmaoYc-SQA/edit?usp=sharing)

As you can see, it will work if column A didn't have any value on it.
[image]

But when I put something in column A, it will look like this.
[image]

Here's the code for hiding the rows:

```js
var startRow = 6;
var colToCheck = 2;

function script_HideRows() {
  var sheetNames = ["MS_Q1", "MS_Q2", "MS_Q3", "MS_Q4", "SUMMARY"];  // Please set the sheet names here. In this case, 4 sheets are used.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      if (sheetName == "SUMMARY") {  // When the sheet is "SUMMARY", the start row is changed.
        startRow = 7;
      }
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
    }
  });
}
```

I got that code from here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691313/6729785)

I just want to hide all the rows that have an empty cell within the column B.

I hope someone can help me.  Sorry for the poor English. Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) you haven't posted the full code, there are functions and variables used in this code snippet that are not defined anywhere. 2) I checked the sheet you shared, and when you select `var colToCheck = 2` which means column B, the code works fine. 3) Having said all that, what is the error you are encountering? Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: From your script in your question, I guessed the modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `numRows - startRow` might be different from the length of `elements`. So in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (var i=0; i<(numRows - startRow); i++) {
```

#### To:

```
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks again! It works fine with the spreadsheet that I gave here. But when I transfer it to the spreadsheet that I'm working, the row before the female 1 is still not hidden. Why it is like that?

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `But when I transfer it to the spreadsheet that I'm working, the row before the female 1 is still not hidden.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Can I see the sample Spreadsheet that you are seeing the issue?

Comment: Here's the spreadsheet that I'm working on. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfnLzSTjoN7OvlOI3pMExLQUunKceXEWA1v1vii8RYY/edit#gid=2144992552)

Comment: As you can see in A31, that row didn't hide even though there is no text in B31.

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. When I saw your current Spreadsheet, I'm surprised that the Spreadsheet is changed from `Here's a sample spreadsheet that I'm trying to do: LINK` in your question. My answer is for your this question. I think that the reason of your new issue is due to that the Spreadsheet is changed. At first, how about resolving your this question? Can I ask you whether my answer could be resolved your question for `Here's a sample spreadsheet that I'm trying to do: LINK`? If you can cooperate to resolve your issues, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve them?

Comment: Yes, it works with that. It is the sample spreadsheet and the one that I gave here in the comment section is the spreadsheet that I'm originally working on. I just apply the solutions there and just changed the startRow value. Sorry for the confusion.