# Apply script depends on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My concern is similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030620/google-sheets-run-script-to-another-sheet-via-button). I just want to ask if how can I modify the codes below for it to work depends on the value in the `column B`? As you can see in the thread that I mentioned earlier, it uses the `const lock_row10 = () => Lock("MTB_Q1");` script. Will that work for this one too?

In the script below, it removes all the settings in the **Protected Sheets & Ranges**. So my concern is how can I just apply the script on the sheet where the button is aligned?
Here's the code:

```
const row10 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B10').getValue();
const unpro_row10 = () => unprotect(row10);

function doGet(e) {
  this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('It worked!');
}

function unprotect() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=un_protect", {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

}

function un_protect(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sh=>sh.getSheetName());
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
 });
}
```

This script `const unpro_row10 = () => unprotect(row10);` is working but it removes all the settings. Maybe some the `un_protect` function is the problem?

And here's the visual:

[image: Picture]

The data in `Column B` are the sheet name of the file. So if ever I'll click the button in `Row 10`, the script should apply to `MS_Q1`. Same as the other rows.

**SOLUTION**

This may seem a long method, but it works for me.

First, remove this `const unpro_row10 = () => unprotect(row10);`

For the `unprotect` function, change it to this:

```
function unpro_row10() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=un_protect&sheetName=" + row10, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

}
```

For the other rows, just duplicate the script above then just change the `row10` to other rows.

For the `un_protect`, change it to this:

```
function un_protect(sheetName){
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var protection = sheet1.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
}
```

Assigned script for the button should be `unpro_row10`.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a long method, but it works for me.

First, remove this `const unpro_row10 = () => unprotect(row10);`

For the `unprotect` function, change it to this:

```
function unpro_row10() {
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=un_protect&sheetName=" + row10, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

}
```

For the other rows, just duplicate the script above then just change the `row10` to other rows.

For the `un_protect`, change it to this:

```
function un_protect(sheetName){
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var protection = sheet1.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
}
```

Assigned script for the button should be `unpro_row10`.