# TypeError: this[e.parameter.run] is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

This is related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031013/google-sheet-exception-request-failed-for-https-script-google-com-returned?noredirect=1#comment114970342_65031013). I don't know what the problem is since I'm just new with this coding thing. But I found the error when I clicked the `latest code` below the URL.

[image: WebApp]

This is the error `TypeError: this[e.parameter.run] is not a function (line 2, file "Code")`.

And, this is the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  this[e.parameter.run](e.parameter.sheetName || null); //this is line 2
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}
```

Honestly, I don't know what that function does since I just copy it on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64689629/6729785). But as far as I understand, it helps for the script to be accessible to other users. What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

You function `doGet(e)` expects a parameter `run` to which the name of an (existing) function is assigned.

- This paramter has to be appended to the WebApp URL
- If you call the WebApp without assigning it any paramater (by pressing on `latest code`) the function will error
- Instead, you need to copy the `Current web app URL` and append to it `?run=NameOfFunction`
- For example:
  `https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXX/exec?run=myFunction`

- If your script contains a function called `myFunction()` - this function will be executed on pasting the full Web App URL including parameter `run` into the browser address bar.

Recomendation

- Modify
   `return ContentService.createTextOutput();`
  to  `return ContentService.createTextOutput("It worked");`
- This will give you some feedback about the fact that the Web App has been executed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!