# Allow shared users to run the app script on a protected sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I can't figure out how to integrate web app on my Apps Script. If there's any other way, or if there's a simple code that would enable shared users that are unauthorized to run the script that will add/edit values/format to a protected sheet, please do help me.

I created a simple test sheet and here's what i came up so far:

```
var ss1         = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var ss2         = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ySKatMCTXrmh1oEGph52o6a0JPoTmV2rn4ybZnxvK7Q')
var data        = ss1.getSheetByName('Data')
var transfer    = ss1.getSheetByName('Transfer')
var file_import = ss2.getSheetByName('file_Import')
var dataval     = data.getRange('B1').getValue()
const url       = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
const options   = {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}

function doGet(e){return ContentService.createTextOutput()}

//this function will run on clicking the Transfer button and will supposedly run the wa_btn_Transfer function
function btn_Transfer(){UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=wa_btn_Transfer" , options)}

//this function will run on clicking the Import button and will supposedly run the wa_btn_Import function
function btn_Import(){UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=wa_btn_Import" , options)}

//this function is to transfer the data set to the same spreadsheet but different sheet
function wa_btn_Transfer(){transfer.getRange('A1').setValue(dataval)}

//this function is to transfer the data set to another locked spreadsheet
function wa_btn_Import(){file_import.getRange('A1').setValue(dataval)}
```

The json file is as follows:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

I put 2 buttons on my spreadsheet
1st button is supposed to run `btn_transfer` function which transfers the selected data to another locked sheet.

2nd button is supposed to run `btn_import` function which transfers the selected data to another spreadsheet that isn't shared and is locked.

As usual, there isn't any problem if the owner(myself) runs the 2 functions. however, what I do need to happen is if I were to share my Google spreadsheet to a user that isn't authorized to edit protected sheets, they should also be able to run the two functions.

I've tried the guides that were already here on Stack Overflow mainly these 3:

1. [Google Sheets - Run script with Sheet Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673622/google-sheets-run-script-with-sheet-protection)
2. [How to enable not authorized users to protect the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086095/how-to-enable-not-authorized-users-to-protect-the-spreadsheet)
3. [Changing Owner of the Sheet irrespective of the duplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666605/changing-owner-of-the-sheet-irrespective-of-the-duplicator)

However, I got no luck with tweaking these 3. I also read the guide from google developers [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) but turns out it isn't beginner friendly. I just need a way to make my script work somehow so here i am.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While it's expected that askers include links to the most relevant posts from this site that they have reviewed, it's also expected that they be specific about what they have tried. Please show what you have tried or make a specfic question regarding what was not clear of one of the link posts.

Comment: I updated the post and that was what i came up with so far. i tried to duplicate each code from the 3 guides i sited and didn't work so I just got what seems to be the most consistent piece on the guides and tried to incorporate it to my code.

im not sure what to call functions in the doGet function and the script that's supposed to get the authorization is getting errors so i'm stuck on what to do

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question still doesn't include enough details. Add the appsscript.json file, describe how the users will use the script (it's not clear which function is exectued and how).

Comment: Please don't make changes to question that invalidates the current answer(se). If you need clarification from the answer(s), add a comment, if you need to do a follow-up question, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, replace

```
const url       = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

by

```
const url       = 'put_here_the_web_app_url_having_/exec';
```

Or, if you are using Google Workspace accounts, move the spreadsheet to a Shared Drive.

**Second**, replace

```
function doGet(e){return ContentService.createTextOutput()}
```

by

```
function doGet(e){
  if(e.parameter && e.parameter.run === 'wa_btn_Transfer'){
    wa_btn_Transfer();
  } else 
  if(e.parameter && e.parameter.run === 'wa_btn_Import'){
    wa_btn_Import();
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput()
}
```

---

Regarding "First"

The script doesn't work for spreadsheet editors because the use of `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` to get the web app URL as this method, when it's run by calling a function in bounded spreadsheet or from the Apps Script editor, returns the test URL (having `/dev`) instead of the web app URL (having `/exec`). The test URL only works for the script / container owner.

Regarding "Second"

The doGet function wasn't doing anything else than returning a `ContentService.TextOutput` object. The proposed change use if statments using a conditional expression having two parts, the first evalutes if the event object includes the `parameter` attribute, the second if the `run` attribute of `parameter` is equal to the expected values, and in such case call the corresponding function.

Comment: i've replaced 'const url       = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()'
to web app url with a '/dev' at the end

and now, the script doesn't do anything anymore when executing as owner and when i execute as a shared user, it still gets an error of can't edit a protected cell

Comment: The URL with `/dev` "at the end" is the test URL, you have you use the URL with `/exec`

Comment: ok. so went with /exec on the web app url. When running the actual scripts `wa_btn_***`, it works but when running it through  web app `btn_Transfer` and `btn_Import`, the script doesn't do anything. The actual script are the `wa_btn_***` and I intend to run the `wa_btn_Transfer` with the `btn_Transfer`. Is there something wrong with the line `{UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?run=wa_btn_Transfer" , options)}` or i need to put something on the doGet function?

Comment: After exploring possibilities, I'm seeing the light now. Thanks so much i got this far. The last problem is it can't import data to other spreadsheets with a restricted access. it's either I open the `general access to anyone with the link` which is obviously dangerous or is there a way to bypass the security of the other spreadsheet using web app?